# Iterating over a pandas sparse series, without the missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with very sparse columns. I would like to iterate over the DataFrame's values but without the missing ones, to save time.

I can't find how to access the indexes of the non-empty cells.

For example:

```py
a = pd.Series([2, 3, 0, 0, 4], dtype='Sparse[int]')
print(a.sparse.sp_values)  # --> [2,3,4]
print(a.sparse.sp_index)   # --> AttributeError
print(a.sparse.to_coo())   # --> ValueError
```

I got the non-empty values, but where is the index? In the above example I am looking for `[0,1,4]`.

I looked at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html) which doesn't seem to mention it. I found information only for SparseArray but not for a Series/DataFrame of sparse type.

Printing `dir(a.sparse)` (without those starting with '_'):

```
['density', 'fill_value', 'from_coo', 'npoints', 'sp_values', 'to_coo', 'to_dense']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) from [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) :

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(a).tolist()
print(idx)
​#[0, 1, 4]
```

Or [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)'s with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
idx = a.ne(0).loc[lambda s: s].index.tolist() # or list(a[a.ne(0)].index)
print(idx)
#[0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! `flatnonzero` improved run time. It still seems to me like it runs over all the values (including missing ones), is that the case?